Cache response from a request in python
I'm writing some backend scripts in python that have to be coupled with a web interface that uses django.
The web application allows to view layers that comes from different web services. As part of my tasks I developed a tool that request elevation data from a geoserver (a WCS service) and then, based on the a previous line drew by a user in the front end, is able to generate a cross section of the underlying data.
So, in short: when a user draws a line over a layer and then clicks draw-profile, my function request the data, intersects the line when the associated raster/layer and returns a figure to the front-end.
The problem with that approach is that each time the user clicks draw-profile, the request is made again, which takes some time.
When the request is made, the data is stored in a DTM object (class that I made) in a self.raster property.
A simplified version of the function that requests the data is shown below.
def get_dtm_from_wcs100(
    self,
    raster_source: str = "YY",
    layer: str = "XX",
    format: str = "image/tiff",
    version: str = "1.0.0",
    resx: int = 1,
    resy: int = 1,
) -> None:
    """
    Get raster and metadata from a WCS service

    Parameters
    ----------
    raster_source : str, optional
        URL of WCS service. The default is "YY" which is the company geoserver
    layer : str, optional
        CoverageID. The default is 'XX'.
    format : str, optional
        File type of the request. The default is 'image/tiff'.
    version : str, optional
        Version of the WCS protocol. The default is "1.0.0".
    resx : int, optional
        Pixel resolution in x-coordinate. The default is 1.
    resy : int, optional
        Pixel resolution in y-coordinate. The default is 1.

    Returns
    -------
    None.

    """

    try:
        # Connect to WCS and try getting a coverage
        wcs = WebCoverageService(raster_source, version=version)
        response = wcs.getCoverage(
            identifier=layer,
            bbox=self.bbox,
            crs=self.epsg,
            format=format,
            resx=resx,
            resy=resy,
        )

    except Exception as e:
        raise Exception("An unexpected error has ocurred:", e)

    else:
        self._read_response(response)
        self._set_masked_raster()

When self._read_response(response) runs the self.raster (numpy array) property is filled.
Do you know what could I do in order to store somehow this response and not have to call it each time I want to draw a profile? Another alternative that I think is to save the python object to a temporary file. Is is possible to store the object in a temporary file so that the file is available until the user finishes his session in the app? (I don't really know how django works. I only deal with the backend scripts)

You could use the @cache decorator of python's functools.
https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html

You could use a memory caching service like Memcached, Redis, etc and tie the user session to a cached version of the response from the WebCoverageService.
You could also serialize the response (mapping it to the user session) and store it locally.
Your approach will really depend on the environment you are running this service in. If your service is running on a classic VM infrastructure, think Amazon EC2, the local file cache would work. However if you are running in Kubernetes you really should investigate Memcached, Redis, etc.
